# Syntax error for a subtraction operation inside an 'else if' block?

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, if-statement

I'm getting the following error:

```
/calcTax.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
  grandtotal = $#{subtotal - tax}
```

From this code:

```
print('What amount would you like to calculate tax for?  $')
subtotal = gets.to_i
taxrate = 0.078
tax = subtotal * taxrate
if (tax > 0.0)
  grandtotal = $#{subtotal + tax}
else if (tax < 0.0)
  grandtotal = $#{subtotal - tax}
puts "Tax on $#{subtotal} is $#{tax}, so the grandtotal is $#{grandtotal}."
```

I'm wondering if I need to set `subtotal` to a value in a different way, or what I can do to repair my program?

I'm also getting an `unexpected $end` error on line 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things wrong with your syntax here.

First of all, the `$#{blah}` syntax is only needed (and only valid!) when inserting variables into a quoted string. When you're just performing calculations, you can simply say something like:

```
grandtotal = subtotal + tax
```

You'll also need to add a `then` at the end of both `if` lines, change `else if` to `elsif`, and add an `end` after the second `grandtotal` line. With this work all done, you should have:

```
print('What amount would you like to calculate tax for?  $')
subtotal = gets.to_i
taxrate = 0.078
tax = subtotal * taxrate
if tax > 0.0 then
  grandtotal = subtotal + tax
elsif tax < 0.0 then
  grandtotal = subtotal - tax
end
puts "Tax on $#{subtotal} is $#{tax}, so the grandtotal is $#{grandtotal}."
```

Which seems to work.

Comment: Thanks, man.  I didn't know that the $# crap was for strings. :)

Comment: Would you be able to explain why it's handled differently, though?

Comment: I'm still getting an error on line 10.  I'll add it to the question.  It says, `unexpected $end`.

Comment: `$#{blah}` isn't valid syntax *at all*, which you sort of gloss over.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, It's valid in strings, though, eh?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Yes but the `$` is just a character in the string there, nothing special. No different than `"f#{subtotal}"`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Why is it included in the book, then?  It's strange that the language is packaged with a .pdf file that uses `$#` when `$` has no meaning.

Comment: Also, the `then` is not necessary here. It's only required when then result is written on the same line as the condition.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 What book? What PDF? Ruby isn't packaged with a book.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall `bookofruby.pdf`

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 First, that doesn't come packaged with Ruby, it comes with an IDE. Second, nowhere does it have `$#` outside of a string. Third, it has `"$#{subtotal}"` because there's supposed to be a "$" in the string—subtotal is money, after all—and it produces (given `subtotal = 3.14`) `"$3.14"`.